# What is the return type of a custom iterator that returns std::iter::Scan?

Tags: rust, types

I tried to turn the following function, which skips the last item of an iterator, into an extension of `Iterator`:

```rust
fn skip_last<T>(mut it: impl Iterator<Item = T>) -> impl Iterator<Item = T> {
    let last = it.next();
    it.scan(last, |state, item| std::mem::replace(state, Some(item)))
}
```

I've mangled it into [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9fa2ca6ef338afa3b0f20dba6e43a2be):

```rust
 trait SkipLast: Iterator {
    fn skip_last(mut self) -> std::iter::Scan<
        Self,
        Option<<Self as Iterator>::Item>,
        FnMut(&mut Option<<Self as Iterator>::Item>, Self::Item) -> Option<Self::Item>,
    >
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        let last = self.next();
        self.scan(last, |state, item| std::mem::replace(state, Some(item)))
    }
}
```

It doesn't compile due to a type error. What should the type actually be for this to compile?

Comment: You can use the method shown in the linked question for yours since your closure doesn't capture anything. You can also make capturing closures work with `Box<dyn FnMut ...>`, and 6 weeks from now in Rust 1.75, you should also be able to just put `impl Iterator<Item = Self::Item>`.

Comment: @drewtato Actually, I think your comment helps me more. This is stylistically motivated. If I can just wait 6 weeks and can thereafter avoid the type altogether that's what I'm doing!

Comment: That's great! I'll add a new answer to the other question with the new method. You can use it now on the nightly or beta channel of Rust.